# SMACH tutorial: ImportError: No module named msg

Tags: ros, executive-smach, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got error while trying to run the ./examples/state_machine.py in smach_tutorials package

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tienthanh/workspace/ros/fuerte/mebios/tienthanh/executive_smach_tutorials/smach_tutorials/examples/state_machine.py", line 21, in 
import smach_ros
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/executive_smach/smach_ros/src/smach_ros/**init**.py", line 55, in 
from action_server_wrapper import ActionServerWrapper
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/executive_smach/smach_ros/src/smach_ros/action_server_wrapper.py", line 9, in 
from actionlib.simple_action_server import SimpleActionServer
File "/home/tienthanh/workspace/ros/fuerte/mebios/tienthanh/executive_smach_tutorials/smach_tutorials/examples/actionlib.py", line 27, in 
from actionlib.msg import *
ImportError: No module named msg

Output of "echo $PYTHONPATH" is
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:

I use ROS fuerte, Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44062/smach-tutorial:-importerror:-no-module-named-msg/) by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the tutorial was never updated when actionlib.

The line should read:

```
from actionlib_msgs.msg import *
```

I've filed a ticket here: https://kforge.ros.org/smach/trac/ticket/2

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on 2012-09-19**:
I change in smach_tutorials/examples/actionlib.py as you advice:
from actionlib_msgs.msg import *

But I got another error:
...
action_server_wrapper.py", line 9, in 
from actionlib.simple_action_server import SimpleActionServer
ImportError: No module named simple_action_server

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ..

I had the same problem when I try to run the ./examples/state_machine.py in smach_tutorials package ...

There is a file called examples/actionlib.py in the same folder.
Rename the file actionlib.py to actionlib1.py and delete the file actionlib.pyc.

With that change I could run all the tutorial examples.

---

Originally posted by [MKnight](https://answers.ros.org/users/3322/mknight/) with karma: 51 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on 2014-08-01**:
Great! This work for me, thanks !